# Spark Scala - processing different child dataframes parallely in bulk

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql, outliers

I am working on a fraudulent transaction detection project which makes use of spark and primarily uses rule-based approach to risk score incoming transactions. For this rule based approach, several maps are created from the historical data to represent the various patterns in transactions and these are then used later while scoring the transaction. Due to rapid increase in data size, we are now modifying code to generate these maps at each account level.

earlier code was  for eg.

`createProfile(clientdata)`

but now it becomes

`accountList.map(account=>createProfile(clientData.filter(s"""account=${account}""")))`

Using this approach , the profiles are generated but since this operations are happening sequentially , hence it doesn't seem to be feasible.

Also, createProfile function itself is making use of dataframes, sparkContext/SparkSessions hence, this is leading to the issueof not able to send these tasks to worker nodes as based on my understanding only driver can access the dataframes and sparkSession/sparkContext. Hence , the following code is not working

`import sparkSession.implicit._
val accountListRdd=accountList.toSeq.toDF("accountNumber")
accountList.rdd.map(accountrow=>createProfile(clientData.filter(s"""account=${accountrow.get(0).toString}""")))`

The above code is not working but represents the logic for the desired output behaviour.

Another approach, i am looking at is using multithreading at driver level using scala Future .But even in this scenario , there are many jvm objects being created in a single `createProfile` function call , so by increasing threads , even if this approach works , it can lead to a lot jvm objects, which itself canlead to garbage collection and memory overhead issues.

just to put timing perspective, createProfile takes about 10 min on average for a single account and we have 3000 accounts , so sequentially it will take many days. With multi threading even if we achieve a factor of 10 , it will take many days. So we need parallelism in the order of 100s .

One of things that could have worked in case it existed was ..lets say if there is Something like a spark groupBy within a groupBY kind of operation, where at first level we can group By "account" and then do other operations
(currently issue is UDF won't be able to handle the kind of operations we want to perform)

Another solution if practically possible is the way SPark Streaming works-
it has a `forEachRDD` method and also `spark.streaming.concurrentjobs` parameter which allows processing of multiple RDDs in parallel . I am not sure how it works but maybe that kind of implementation may help.

Above is the problem description and my current views on it.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this! Also ,I will prefer a logical change rather than suggestion of different technology